# Could Google detect Cloaking if I displayed content to Google user agent using PHP

Tags: seo, php, cloaking

PHP is server side and all Googlebot would see is the output HTML, right?

```
if (strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],"Googlebot")) { // do some functionality }
```

Comment: Yes because they send out SpyBots to fetch your site without using the user agent 'Googlebot' and compare the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defeating this is easy and has nothing to do with doing this on the server side. All they have to do is compare a page that you serve to the Googlebot user agent and one to a bot or human that is not. The pages will be different and you will be caught and penalized for cloaking. It's *that* simple.

Comment: In fact, Google has been hitting sites from outside of their network for a vary long time for just this purpose.

Comment: I just want to put a link to a website on a site I built, nothing sinister everyone can get off their knees from praying to the almighty G